# This code for Horizontally displaying the text in pdf, how do I change it into vertically on my pdf pages

Tags: java, pdf, itext

This code for Horizontally displaying the text in pdf, how do I change it into vertically on my pdf pages

```
private  void stampPdf(InputStream source, OutputStream dest) throws Exception {
  PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(source), new PdfWriter(dest));
  Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
  Paragraph header = new Paragraph("Received by on")
    .setFont(PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA))
    .setFontSize(14)       
    .setFontColor(Color.RED).setRotationAngle(90);
  for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDoc.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
    float x = pdfDoc.getPage(i).getPageSize().getLeft();
    float y = pdfDoc.getPage(i).getPageSize().getTop() -30;
    doc.showTextAligned(header.setFontColor(Color.RED), x, y, i,
    TextAlignment.RIGHT, VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0);   
  }
  doc.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
doc.showTextAligned(header.setFontColor(Color.RED), x, y, i,
TextAlignment.RIGHT, VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0);
```

with

```
doc.showTextAligned(header.setFontColor(Color.RED), x, y, i,
TextAlignment.RIGHT, VerticalAlignment.TOP, 90);
```

Comment: Im getting the vaertical but the line is showing crossly. below view the attachment i have attached

Comment: Please see the image description in the question.

Comment: play with the rotation value a bit

Comment: its gone while im changing the the value. any help